# Maven packaging failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gmall-pms: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.atguigu:gmall-pms:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.atguigu:gmall-common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9q91.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO7MM.jpg)

Delete the original file and repackage

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing dependency package during compilation. Please package com. atgui: gmall common: jar: 0.0.1 SNAPSHOT first

Comment: common install success. pms package fail。still this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to change gmall common version to 0.0.2 SNAPSHOT and reinstall.Or restart idea. Once there are too many dependencies, maven will make mistakes.